# Can't add shortcut to app launcher

Tags: slingshot, resolution, app-shortcuts

I've downloaded Cisco PacketTracer and ran it normally from terminal with a `./PacketTracer7` command in packettracer's Bin folder. No problem there. The problem is, i can't add it to the launcher (with App-Editor) or pin it to plank. I need to run it exactly from that folder.

I can install it and run it from the menu, but it messes the app window resolution.  Everything looks huge. So i need to launch it from that path.
Is there a way around it?
I tried `sh /home/user/packettracer/PacketTracer7` in App-Editor, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

I made a desktop file in `~.local/share/applications/` with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application

Exec=/home/USER/PacketTracer/bin/PacketTracer7
Icon=/home/USER/PacketTracer/art/pkz.png
Path=/home/USER/PacketTracer/bin/
Name=Cisco Packet Tracer
Categories=Application;Network;

MimeType=application/x-pkt;application/x-pka;application/x-pkz;
```

The shortcut immediately appeared in app launcher.

Answer (score 0):

Pardon me for asking this in the answer section, but I don't have a high enough reputation to ask in the comment section.

1) What version of elementary are you using?

I can get Packet Tracer to install and run just fine in Loki, but I have issues with running it in Juno.

2) Whether it's Loki or Juno, it looks like Packet Tracer's desktop file is incorrect.

If you go to `/usr/share/applications`, the **pt7.desktop** file looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=PacketTracer7
Icon=pt7
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=Packet Tracer 7.2
```

I changed it to:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=packettracer
Icon=/opt/pt/art/app.ico
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=Packet Tracer 7.2
Categories=Development;IDE;
```

and then it puts an icon under Programming in the Application menu.

In Loki, I can alternate-click and select "Keep in Dock" to put it on the Plank. I can also run it just fine - even without any resolution problems.

However, in Juno, I can't get it to run from the menu or from the terminal. If I type `packettracer` in the terminal, It says `Starting Packet Tracer 7.2` but it never runs.

UPDATE: Packet Tracer does appear to have another .desktop file than the one that ends up in `/usr/share/applications`.  It's in /opt/pt/bin and it's called **Cisco-PacketTracer.desktop**. It's contents are:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application

Exec=packettracer %F
Icon=/opt/pt/art/app.png

Name=Cisco Packet Tracer
Categories=Application;Network;

MimeType=application/x-pkt;application/x-pka;application/x-pkz;
```

But still can't get it working in Juno - even with your method of **./PacketTracer7**. I get the following message:

> error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: I'm using Juno.
I found a workaround somewhere like this:
`wget -q -O /tmp/libpng12.deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb \
  && sudo dpkg -i /tmp/libpng12.deb \
  && rm /tmp/libpng12.deb`

Now i just keep the .deb file in case i need it. But i do have resolution problems in a full hd display, if i install it.

Comment: Thanks, Telmo. After installing libpng12 on Juno, I can now run Packet Tracer.

Comment: Fantastic. I've come across other dependency issues after installing. So i'm not installing for now, if you have any issue, just post here and i'll try to help..